# MS Graph API/Workbooks (Excel API): Updating a cell format in a UseRange

Tags: c#, excel, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

### What's I'm doing well

I'm currently creating an dotnet core app to consume and process data from an Excel sheet stored in personal OneDrive. I'm using `MSAL` to create a session token and the data consumption is working great.  Here's my **working code**:

```cs
// Get the range for data to process
var dataRangeRequest = myGraphServiceClient // an instance of GraphServiceClient
    .Me.Drive.Items[fileItemId]
    .Workbook
    .Sheets[sheetId]
    .UsedRange(valuesOnly: false)
    .Request();

var dataRange = await dataRangeRequest.GetAsync(ct)

// Extract column names (headers) from the data range
var columnNames = dataRange.Text.First.ToObject<string[]>();
// Extract data cells from the data range
var lines = dataRange.Text.Skip(1).Select(line=>line.ToObject<string[]>).ToArray();
[...] // Here I process the lines using the columnNames.

// --EVERYTHING WORKS UNTIL HERE--
```

### What I'm not doing well

Now, I want to **turn red a faulty data cell** in the original Excel document

```cs
var faultyCell = (row: 34, column: 5); // the row/column offset of the faulty cell in dataRange

// ---------------------------------
// --FOLLOWING CODE IS NOT WORKING--
// ---------------------------------
var changeRange = new WorkbookRange
    {
        RowIndex = faultyCell.row,
        ColumnIndex = faultyCell.column,
        RowCount = 1,
        ColumnCount = 1,
        Format = new WorkbookRangeFormat {Fill = new WorkbookRangeFill {Color = "red"}}
    };
await dataRangeRequest.PatchAsync(changeRange, ct); // Throwing a Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
```

I intercepted the HTTP request & response and it's the following:

REQUEST

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<file id>/workbook/worksheets/{sheetId}/microsoft.graph.usedRange(valuesOnly=true) HTTP/1.1

{
    "columnIndex": 5,
    "rowIndex": 34,
    "columnCount": 1,
    "rowCount": 1,
    "format": {
        "fill": {
            "color": "Red",
            "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.workbookRangeFill"
        },
        "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.workbookRangeFormat"
    },
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.workbookRange"
}
```

RESPONSE

```
400 Bad Request

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request - Error in query syntax.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "<the date>",
      "request-id": "<a guid>",
     "client-request-id": "<another guid>"
   }
 }
}
```

### Success with a manual HTTP request

I succeed to update manually the cell using a HTTP request by [following the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/rangeformat-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request).

WORKING REQUEST:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/<file id>/workbook/worksheets/{sheetId}/range(address='F35:F35')/format/fill

{"color": "red"}
```

### Problems

1. I don't know **how to generate this HTTP request** from C# by using the `Microsoft.Graph` api. (the documentation is obsoleted, there's no `.Format` on `IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuilder`. This error seems [documented on GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/8710). Is there an easy way to use the graph SDK to send an arbritary http request?
2. More importantly: for this to work, I need to **translate the cell offset to a range address**. Is there an utility somewhere to do that? In my example I manually translated the offset `5,34` in the range to address `F35`.

### Specifications

Packages:

- `Microsoft.Graph`: `v3.15.0` (latest *release* version)
- `Microsoft.Identity.Client`: (MSAL) `v4.15.0` (not the latest version, but shoudn't be a problem here)

Comment: Outside of Graph SDK, have you tried testing the same call with POSTMAN/MS Graph Explorer? Does it work?

Comment: Also, what was the last known version (MS Graph SDK) worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm, that this issue with no `.Format` on `IWorkbookWorksheetRangeRequestBuilder` is frustrating for me as well ;) I've reported this issue on GitHub:

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/233

For me the workaround was to do it like so (i was basing it on this SOF: [REST call to Microsoft Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48693630/rest-call-to-microsoft-graph)

```
        var requestUrl = $@"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/drive/items/{Consts.DriveId}/workbook/worksheets/{Consts.SheetId}/range(address='{range}')/{resource}";

        string workbookRangeFill = GraphServiceClient.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeObject(workbookRange);

        // Create the request message and add the content.
        HttpRequestMessage hrm = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(httpMethod), requestUrl);
        hrm.Content = new StringContent(workbookRangeFill, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        // Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
        await GraphServiceClient.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

        // Send the request and get the response.
        HttpResponseMessage response = await GraphServiceClient.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
```

Whereas `workbookRange` variable is of either of type: `WorkbookRangeFill` or `WorkbookRangeFont` (Depending on the need) I assume you will be interested in `WorkbookRangeFill` (to change the color in range/cell)

`range` variable is range in spreadsheet in the format: "A1:B3"

`resource` variable is `format/fill` for `WorkbookRangeFill` and `format/font` for `WorkbookRangeFont`

and of course `{user id}` is the user which owns the document (i am using `client credentials flow with` with `application permisions` For other scenarios i assume you can just change one thing in the code above. So that, instead of:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user id}/drive`

to use

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive`